# Python Tkinter Scrollbar isn't displayed and doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I tried to add a Scrollbar widget to my python Tkinter app. The problem is that it is not displayed and when I want to add some widget to the frame in which is placed the scrollbar those widgets are hidden. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(window)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: 
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

label_width = [26, 7, 10, 10, 10, 13, 19, 9, 7, 19, 10, 9, 10, 13, 10, 21, 9, 22]   
x_location = [0, 210, 269, 353, 437, 521, 629, 785, 861, 921, 1075, 1159,1230, 1313, 1420, 1503, 1670, 1740]
data = [["Stefan", "20", "2001"], ["Andrew", "15", "2006"], ["John", "10", "2003"]]
results = [[data[j][i] for j in range(len(data))] for i in range(len(data[0]))]

y = 0
for result in results:
    x = 0
    for i in result:
        share_detail = Label(scrollable_frame, text=i, anchor="center", borderwidth=2, relief="solid", width=label_width[x], font=("Calibri", 11))
        share_detail.place(x=x_location[x], y=22 * (y + 1))
        x += 1
    y += 1
container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

window.mainloop()
```

The variable "results" is 2d array of string, in case is helping anyhow. So what's wrong with the code?

Comment: This code won't run as posted. You haven't defined `results` or `label_width` or `x_location`. Please make sure your [mcve] is runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't run as posted. However, one obvious problem is that you are configuring the scrollregion whenever the `<Configure>` event is fired on the frame, but you're using `place` which won't cause that event to be triggered.

This trick to reconfigure `scrollregion` only works when the frame resizes and `place` doesn't cause a parent widget -- in this case, `scrollable_frame` -- to grow or shrink. You'll need to use `pack` or `grid` on the labels, or explicitly resize the frame.

Comment: And how do I use 'pack' or 'grid' to set the exact same coordinates for the Labels?

Comment: @iAmStefan: why do you need the exact same coordinates? What are you trying to achieve?